# How can we prevent files that have changed the extension from being uploaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, header-files, .net-framework-version

I have a program that allow to user upload a file.

Suppose the user is only allowed to upload the psd file (or any other file that is specified by admin user). If user changes the file extension from .exe to psd, can upload it.

How can we prevent files that have changed the extension from being uploaded?

Comment: Check for jpeg header.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for ContentType header, but that could be tampered by someone with enough knowledge to do so.
Like MrTux pointed out, the best way would be to read the file header and check if it's complying to the file format you want to check against.
It would be easy to decide if you have information on how users are currently uploading files. If it's your own system or if users compose their own http post requests.

Comment: I know how to check header of image files so how should I check other file types header? (like .docx, .psd, .xlsx , etc)

Comment: You have to check each file type format to understand it's signature and implement a check on top of that.
You can start here https://asecuritysite.com/forensics/file
But it's not that hard to find information about file headers, just google like 'psd file header' and so on...